# Java: custom to byte conversions

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, byte

I am working with some low capacity module and I need to compress the data as much as possible. The data will look like this:

DeviceEvent:

- 1 byte:

  - 2 bits for status (00 each time)
  - 6 bits for rgb color (3 x 2 bits)
- 2 bytes: number of minutes from now to a certain datetime

I need to create a constructor (preferably 2 constructors) for conversion from/to:

Event:

- byte[] color (rgb, colors will get simplified to only 64 available)
- some datetime (but I will get the integer for difference in minutes and it will be small enough to fit in two bits)

So basically I need:

- byte[3] color <-> 1 byte status and color
- int minutes <-> byte[2]
  minutes

I will be thankful for any help

Comment: so, what is your problem?

Comment: you need but you dont know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not very sure what is your problem, probably this will help:

```
final byte red = 1; // 01 binary
final byte green = 2; // 10 binary
final byte blue = 3; // 11 binary

final byte finalColor = (byte) ((red & 0x3) << 4) | ((green & 0x3) << 2) | (blue & 0x3);
System.out.println(finalColor);// finalColor is 011011 = 27 decimal

final int minutes = 0x1234; // first byte is 0x12, second byte is 0x34
final byte[] bytes = {(byte) (((minutes) >>> 8) & 0xff), (byte) (minutes & 0xff)};

System.out.println(bytes[0]); // 0x12 = 18 decimal
System.out.println(bytes[1]); // 0x34 = 52 decimal
```

Comment: Thanks. This is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what the second problem is. So I made these two functions that might help you:

```
public static int convertToInt(int a, int b, int c, int d) {
    a = Math.min(a, 255);
    b = Math.min(b, 255);
    c = Math.min(c, 255);
    d = Math.min(d, 255);

    return ((a & 0xFF) << 24) | ((b & 0xFF) << 16) | ((c & 0xFF) << 8) | (d & 0xFF);
}

public static int[] extractComponents(int data) {
    int a = (data >> 24) & 0xFF;
    int b = (data >> 16) & 0xFF;
    int c = (data >> 8) & 0xFF;
    int d = data & 0xFF;

    return new int[] {a, b, c, d};
}
```

The `convertToInt` function takes four numbers(that are less than 255) and puts them all in one int.

The `extractComponents` function does the opposite.

This is an example:

```
int data = 0xC8E0601B;
int[] dataA = extractComponents(data);
for(int i = 0 ; i < dataA.length; i++) System.out.printf("%x\n", dataA[i]);

System.out.printf("%x\n", convertToInt(dataA[0], dataA[1], dataA[2], dataA[3]));
```